# Reusable Component in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, styled-components

I wanted to create a reusable component in my React app using Styled-Components. My problem is that i got the error

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

pls check my code below:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import React from 'react'

const CustomSpinner = styled.svg`
  animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;

  & .path {
    stroke: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.black};
    stroke-linecap: round;
    animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
  }

  @keyframes rotate {
    100% {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
  @keyframes dash {
    0% {
      stroke-dasharray: 1, 150;
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    50% {
      stroke-dasharray: 90, 150;
      stroke-dashoffset: -35;
    }
    100% {
      stroke-dasharray: 90, 150;
      stroke-dashoffset: -124;
    }
  }
`

export const Spinner = ({ className}) => {
  return (
    <CustomSpinner viewBox="0 0 50 50" className={className}>
      <circle className="path" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" strokeWidth="4" />
    </CustomSpinner>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to change the `export const Spinner = (...) =>` to `export default (...) =>`, like so:

```
export default ({ className}) => {
      return (
        <CustomSpinner viewBox="0 0 50 50" className={className}>
          <circle className="path" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" strokeWidth="4" />
        </CustomSpinner>
      )
    }
```

But I would suggest exporting like this instead so you can get full autocomplete from your code editor when importing components:

```
const Spinner = ({ className}) => {
      return (
        <CustomSpinner viewBox="0 0 50 50" className={className}>
          <circle className="path" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" strokeWidth="4" />
        </CustomSpinner>
      )
    }

export default Spinner;
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with how you are importing this component.

When you do

```
export const Spinner = ({ className}) => {
  return (
    <CustomSpinner viewBox="0 0 50 50" className={className}>
      <circle className="path" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" strokeWidth="4" />
    </CustomSpinner>
  )
}
```

Then you need to import it like

`import {Spinner} from 'path/to/Spinner`

and you are likely importing it like

`import Spinner from 'path/to/Spinner'`

The above line imports the default export from spinner, but you don't have a default export, so you need to change your import, or change your export to

```
export default ({ className}) => {
  return (
    <CustomSpinner viewBox="0 0 50 50" className={className}>
      <circle className="path" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" strokeWidth="4" />
    </CustomSpinner>
  )
}
```

instead

Comment: Also instead of having className as a prop, you might just want to use `...props` instead, then you can pass in style and whatever and not have to worry https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-violet-skhp0?file=/src/App.js